# Multiple - Master Detail Pages

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am new to angular (from a meteor background) and I am struggling with  how i would implement 2 master detail style pages in Angular ui router.

What i am trying to achieve is as follows:

Before a person is logged in they would see:
Master Page A Containing:

- Header A
- Content - which changes
- Footer A

When a person logs in they would see:
Master Page B Containing:

- Header B
- Content - which changes by route
- Footer B

Content - changes Footer B

**Firstly**: (I am not sure if the below is correct) So far i have found the following code online, however it seems that i would need to repeat the header and footer on every single route (which seems to re-load these everytime when navigating to different content pages).

```
   .state('home', {
             abstract: true,
             url: '/home',
             views: {
                 'main': {
                     templateUrl: 'app/template/home.html'
                 }
             }
         })
        .state('home.landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            views: {
                'header@home': {
                    templateUrl: "app/template/header.html"
                },
                'test@home': {
                    templateUrl: "app/template/test.html"
                },
                'footer@home': {
                    templateUrl: "app/template/footer.html"
                }
            }
        })
         .state('home.other', {
             url: '/other',
             views: {
                 'header@home': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/header.html"
                 },
                 'test@home': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/test2.html"
                 },
                 'footer@home': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/footer.html"
                 }
             }
         })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to have the header and footer remain constant across children of the home state would be to define those in the home state itself like so.

```
   .state('home', {
             abstract: true,
             url: '/home',
             views: {
                 'main': {
                     templateUrl: 'app/template/home.html'
                 },
                 'header@home': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/header.html"
                 },
                 'footer@home': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/footer.html"
                 }
             }
         })
        .state('home.landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            views: {
                'test': {
                    templateUrl: "app/template/test.html"
                }
            }
        })
         .state('home.other', {
             url: '/other',
             views: {
                 'test': {
                     templateUrl: "app/template/test2.html"
                 }
             }
         })
```

So in the abstract home state, home.html will populate the main ui-view within your root template. Then, header and footer will populate the ui-views within home.html.

For the children states, you could leave the view as test@home, but since it's a direct child of home, you could shorten to just test.